# Sutherland's constant of argon

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I want to compute the viscosity of argon at different temperatures. What is [Sutherland's constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viscosity#Gases) of argon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I meanwhile found the constant by intensive googling (for example in [this article](http://www.cse.scitech.ac.uk/ceg/papers/Gu_et_al_Nanoscale_Microscale_Thermophysical_Eng.pdf)). It is (depending on the source) around 144 K.